# Configuring Always On Availability Groups sql Server 2019 and log backup

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

We want migrate to sql 2019 and I did the test and  set up Hight availability with twho 2 nodes,but and the set up of  AG I have four option,
I gave that option a shared path for the transaction log but I saw that a transaction log was generated, which increased space in the same transaction log every time they made updates and uploads to the database.
Which one would be recommended for a production environment and at the same time how to manage the transaction log?
Should I implement a log shipping strategy with always high availability Group 2019? which is the best option?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As with most things SQL, best is variable and highly dependent on your environment.

If all of my databases were small, then I would choose Automatic Seeding.

Otherwise, I would use Join Only or Skip Initial Data Synchronization (they are really the same, it's if you have done the prep work PRIOR to this step or if yo u want to do it later.

For medium to largish databases, my steps would be:

- Restore a FULL database to the secondary
- Continually restore LOG files to the secondary.
- STOP new log backups on primary (temporary)
- Restore last log backup to secondary (with NORECOVERY)
- Join to Availability Group
- Resume log backups on primary